# Help in LINQ query with group by

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have the following List:

```
1: true; 
2: false;    
2: true;   
3: false;   
3: false;  
3: false;
```

I want a LINQ query to get a collection as the following:

key, OR operation between the grouped items, for example:

```
2: false | true  = true
```

The result must be:

```
1: true   
2: true   
3: false
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// my sample data
var list = new[] {
    new {key = 1, value = true},
    new {key = 2, value = false},
    new {key = 2, value = true},
    new {key = 3, value = false},
    new {key = 3, value = false},
    new {key = 3, value = false},
};
// the actual code
var groups = from pair in list
          group pair by pair.key into grp
          orderby grp.Key
          select new {
              grp.Key,
              Value = grp.Aggregate(false, (x, y) => x || y.value)
          };
// display the result
foreach (var grp in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", grp.Key, grp.Value);
}
```

Note you could also use `Any` to do the aggregate, with the advantage that it will short-circuit sooner:

```
      select new { grp.Key, Value = grp.Any(y => y.value) };
```